# Do I have to explicitly define an observable as "finite"?

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

There are several resources out there ([like this one](https://www.seangwright.me/blog/development/unsubscribe-angular-2-http-observables/)) that define what a "finite" observable is (an observable that eventually stops emitting values). From what I've read, it is generally accepted that finite observables do not need to be unsubscribed from.

Is there anything that needs to be done to explicitly define an Observable as "finite"? [This article](https://lukaonik.medium.com/do-we-need-to-unsubscribe-http-client-in-angular-86d781522b99) shows how the Angular HttpClient calls `complete()` on its `Observer` is something that forces its observers to unsubscribe. Is this what makes it "finite"? Or can an observable be finite just by its nature, without explicitly calling `complete()`? If so, is it safe to NOT unsubscribe from an observable that is finite by nature?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yes and No.

Some observables are finite by construction. This includes all Promises, for example. It also includes

```ts
const someArray = [/* array contents */]
from(someArray).subscribe({
  next: console.log, // Log emissions
  error: _ => {},    // We could ignore errorsby omitting this line, but hey
  complete: () => console.log("This observable completed");
});
```

After the contents of the array are logged, this observable will complete. By construction.

Here's a simplified version of `from` that doesn't complete

```ts
function endlessFrom(array) {
  return new Observable(observer => {
    array.forEach(observer.next.bind(observer))
    // observer.complete(); <- Oh no! ;)
    return {
      unsubscribe: () => {} // Do nothing
    }
  })
}

const someArray = [/* array contents */]
endlessFrom(someArray).subscribe({
  next: console.log, // Log emissions
  error: _ => {},    // We could ignore errorsby omitting this line, but hey
  complete: () => console.log("This observable completed");
});
```

If you run this, you'll see that `"This observable completed"` is never logged. Always, a *finite* observable will call its observer's `complete` or `error` callback **explicitly**. There are no observables that complete via any library magic of any sort.

That being said, many operators do that work for you. `RxJS#from` constructs Promises and Arrays are finite, but you can make **any** source finite with (for example) `take`, `takeWhile`, ect.

---

## But Really: No

There's no runtime flag or property that can make an observable finite. The only way is for that Observable to emit an `error` or `complete`. This makes sense. Even if you could tag an observable as being finite, what mechanism could an observer use to know when an observable had fulfilled its obligation to complete?

Comment: Nice answer! Kudos.

Comment: Thank you so much for your well thought out response. I am marking this as the accepted answer. Extremely enlightening!